# Relationship between geometric multiplicity of a matrix and annihilator polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let, $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. We wish to demonstrate that,
the statement every eigenvalue of $A$ has geometric multiplicity of $1$ is equivalent to the statement every polynomial $p$ that annihilates $A$ has degree at least $n$.

Suppose that every eigenvalue of $A$ has geometric multiplicity of $1$. Let, $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Then the Jordan normal form of $A$ is $J(\lambda_1) \oplus\dots \oplus J(\lambda_r)$ since the geometric multiplicity of every eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$ which means there is $1$ Jordan block corresponding to each eigenvalue of $A$. We can then conclude that,
$$|J(\lambda_1)| + \dots + |J(\lambda_r)| = n,$$
where the $|\cdot|$ operator denotes the size of the matrix. So we can conclude that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ since the power to which eigenvalue is raised to in the minimal polynomial corresponds to the maximum size of the Jordan block corresponding to it in the Jordan decomposition of $A$. Hence,
every polynomial $p$ that annihilates $A$ has degree at least $n$.

Suppose now that every polynomial $p$ that annihilates $A$ has degree at least $n$. We now have that the characteristic poly is equal to the minimal polynomial by definition; hence, the size of the largest Jordan block corresponding to each eigen value of $A$ is equal to the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue which means there can only be $1$ Jordan block corresponding to each eigenvalue which implies the geometric multiplicity of $A$ is 1.

Dos my proof look good? Any issues? Thanks!